# SQL - Foreign key is part of the composite key in the parent causing error

Tags: mysql, excel, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I'm designing a small database and made the relationship model using the MySQLWorkbench 6.3.

[image: 1]

When I try to transfer the relationship to excel by manually creating new relationship, I get this error,

[image: 2]

Error message,

[image: 3]

I'm guessing that's because my task table has a composite primary key instead of only one. What would be the best way of fixing this issue? thanks a lot,

Comment: Your images are not displaying, thanks to update same.

Comment: @GeekyNinja I've got no problem seeing the images, tried on few other machines.

Comment: But I can't able to see any image in your question. Might be url is not accessible.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PHVhc.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7ot6.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KvFQy.png  , can u try these links instead?